# What is the difference between 'rxjs/operators' and 'rxjs/add/operator/'?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

What is the difference between `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';` and `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';` ?

I'm using it in the service method which does a login :

```
// import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'; // Fails at runtime
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; // Works fine at runtime

  public login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    console.log('Sending the login credentials to obtain a token');
    const credentials = { 'email': username, 'password': password };
    return this.httpService.postWithHeadersInResponse(URI_LOGIN, credentials)
      .map((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
        const header = response.headers.get(this.authService.getHeaderName());
        const token = this.authService.extractTokenFromHeader(header);
        console.log('The token from the response header: ' + token);
        this.authService.setJwtTokenToLocalStorage(token);
      });
  }
```

Comment: afaik the first one only imports it into the current file, while the second one makes it available everywhere... maybe you're using it somewhere else without importing and that's why the first one fails but the second makes it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that when you use `rxjs/add/operator/map` it changes prototype of Observable, so you can chain with `.` (dot) operator:

```
this.httpService.postWithHeadersInResponse(URI_LOGIN, credentials)
  .map(...);
```

But this way of using operators was deprecated. Current way with `rxjs/operators`:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
this.httpService.postWithHeadersInResponse(URI_LOGIN, credentials)
  .pipe(map(...));
```

Comment: Moreover, starting from RxJs 6, we should use all operators from `'rxjs/operators'` and some additional in the root `'rxjs'`. If you don't want change anything, you can install `rxjs/compat` dependency for your project to support all already written code using old-style.

Answer (score 1):

RxJs changed the public_api.ts and moved some files in the rxjs-project in a newer version (5.5+ I guess).

The correct way now is:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'
```

The other way will be deprecated/removed in a newer version (I read 7.0 somewhere in a blog). In addition, the other way only works with rxjs-compat in the newer rxjs-versions.

And rxjs-compat will not work anymore with RxJs 7.0 (most likely)